# Primary Key constraint

Tags: primary-key, database-administration

I have written a query to merge two tables data into one. This query works fine when i try to insert values when the primary key values are different. But if i try to insert values which are same(primary key values) in the second table, then it gives me an error saying:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Person'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'.

This is the query which i have written:

insert into DB1.dbo.Person select * from db2.dbo.Person

How do i replace the primary key values or skip that row if there are duplicate primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table of same structure. Inset `Value` without primary key to Temp table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Ya that's possible if I have like 2 to 3 tables, But what if I have 20 to 30 tables that i need to merge the data. It is not possible to create that many temp tables.

Comment: This article will help  you here is the [link](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/using-a-where-cluase-to-join-three-or-more-tables-based-on-a-parent-child-relationship.php)

Comment: I have written a query which merges the data from two tables excluding the primary key data(If present in the 1st table).
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Person(Id,Name,Age)
SELECT Id,Name,Age FROM DB2.dbo.Person
WHERE Id NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM DB1.dbo.Person)

The drawback is that i will have to mention the column names and primary keys as well. I would like to know of there s any other way to do it. I mean without mentioning the column name.

It should take the primary key by default and merge it.